# If statement with the datetime library in python

Tags: python, datetime, if-statement

This is the code i have so far. I want to check if it is a certain date and then print a fitting answer(for special days eg. Birthdays, etc). Only problem is that even tho it tells me todays date is 06/08/2021, when i check for it in the if statement it says its not that date. Why is that

```
from datetime import date

tday = date.today()
print(str(tday))

if str(tday) == "06/08/2021":
    print("Today's date:", tday)
else:
    print("Today's date isn't:", tday)
```

Comment: ```"2021-08-06"``` is never equal to ```"06/08/2021"```. There are several differences

Comment: When your code does `str(tday) == "06/08/2021"` it is checking *strings* not dates. Although those two strings represent the same date, string comparison says they are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to change the 2021/08/06 to 2021-08-06

```
from datetime import date

tday = date.today()
print(str(tday))

if str(tday) == "2021-08-06":
    print("Today's date:", tday)
else:
    print("Today's date isn't:", tday)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `str(tday)` what you are getting is a string like this: `'2021-08-06'`.  Just use another `date` object for the comparison:

```
if tday == date(2021, 8, 6):
    print("message")
else:
    print("other message")
```

**EDIT:** assuming when you say "06/08/2021" you mean 6th August, 2021

**EDIT2:** The order of the arguments are, `year`, `month`, `day`; see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types).

Comment: And if not, just use `date(2021, 6, 8)` to represent 8th June, 2021.

Comment: But this is the right approach: prefer parsing strings to `date` objects over creating string representations of `date` objects.

Comment: And to restore some of the readability, use keyword arguments: `date(year=2021, month=6, day=8)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current date in your desidered format:

```
   tday  = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Then you can check with your previous code block:

```
if str(tday) == "06/08/2021":
    print("Today's date:", tday)
else:
    print("Today's date isn't:", tday)
```